# Is there a better way to create a dictionary key in python than converting to string?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a function that returns an energy associated with a vector in 3D space, F(i,j,k).

F() is a slow function, so I have a dictionary that checks if F() has been called for a specific i,j,k, and if it has then I just take that value from the dictionary.

I'm currently doing this as:

```
key = "_".join( [ str(i), str(j), str(k)  ])

if key not in dic: 
    dic[key] = F(i,j,k)

Energy = dic[key]
```

Is there a better way to create a key than by joining the vectors like this?

Comment: For future reference, that first line can be simplified using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), to `key = "_".join(map(str, (i, j, k)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionary keys can be *anything [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable)*; a tuple of the 3 values does fine:

```
key = i, j, k  # a comma makes this a tuple
try:
    Energy = dic[key]
except KeyError:
    Energy = dic[key] = F(i, j, k)
```

I'm using exception handling here (*asking for forgiveness*) rather than explicitly testing if the key is present (*asking for permission*); the former is faster when the absence of the key is the key is the norm.

Comment: I was using shelve to store my dictionaries. Apparently this won't work with tuples as keys. Is pickle the next best alternative?

Comment: @egoburnswell: `shelve` *uses pickle* as the implementation. Tuple keys should work just fine with shelve; what is the error you see?

Comment: 'TypeError: String or Integer object expected for key, tuple found'

Comment: @egoburnswell: My apologies, I indeed see that `shelve` is documented as only accepting strings as keys. That's because the *values* are pickled, but these are then stored in a [DBM-style file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html), and it is *that* format that limits your keys.

Comment: @egoburnswell: Either store your dictionary *nested* in `shelve` (`shelveobj['data'] = yourdict`, make sure to *reassign to that key on changes*) or use only Pickle, in that case.

Comment: @egoburnswell: that *could* include building a subclass of `shelve.Shelve()` that writes directly to a pickle file on close. Then you can support arbitrary key types. See the [`shelve.py` module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shelve.py) for hints.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python dicts can take any *hashable* object as keys[1], you can just use the `(i, j, k)` tuple:

```
if (i, j, k) not in dic:
    dic[(i, j, k)] = F(i,j,k)
Energy = dic[(i, j, k)]
```

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict